# Google play store requires permission declaration form to be filled out but doesn't provide one

Tags: android

I am making a new test release for a new app and have filled out all requested info related to app content. Uploaded a new bundle and when I click review release, I get presented with errors of the style

```
Error Your background location permission declaration needs to be updated.
Error This release includes permissions that haven't been declared in Play Console. Go to Sensitive app permissions to update your permission declarations. Learn more
Error Your app cannot be published yet. Complete the steps listed on the Dashboard.
```

I would love to do this but there is nothing shown in the dashboard related to this, there were no form displayed during the process as stated by *"The Permissions Declaration Form is displayed during the release process"* and when I look deeper, I see nothing showing up under AppContent, as stated by *"If you have an active app bundle that requires a Permissions Declaration, including releases on the Open, Closed, or Internal test tracks, an alert is displayed on the left menu under App Content"*

My app does request location permissions in its manifest and uses it, but it seems play store wants me to specify this somewhere, but then again it doesn't let me.

I have not seen others with this issue, so either I am really confused, or this is a bug of sorts. Does anyone here know how to handle this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the form in your App's Policy section.

Open Play console -> Select your App -> In the left panel at the bottom end there will be a Policy section. under that section select App content.

[image: play console]

Here you will find the Sensitive Permission and API form in To do :

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately no. That does not show up.. I will add a screenshot of this page to the question for reference.